# Somar valores de um array

Tags: java, array, array-multidimensional

Estou tentando fazer esse código, que é basicamente um array bidimensional 6x6 com a distância entre 6 cidades, depois coletar a rota que o usuário fez em um array simples [6], e calcular o total de quilômetros que ele percorreu.

O código:

```
package rotas;

import java.util.*;


public class Rotas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] km = {{0, 20, 32, 45, 85, 90}, {20, 0, 20, 40, 65, 70}, {32, 20, 0, 25, 48, 49}, 
                        {45, 40, 25, 0, 39, 52}, {85, 65, 48, 39, 0, 36}, {90, 70, 49, 52, 36, 0}};

        int[] rota = new int[6];
        String[] rota_r = new String[6];
        String[] cid = {"Belo Horizonte", "Contagem", "Betim", "Juatuba", "Pará de Minas", "Itaúna"};
        int km_rodados = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
                System.out.printf("%d\t", km[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Digite sua rota: \n\n1. Belo Horizonte\t2. Contagem\t3. Betim\n"
                    + "4. Juatuba\t5. Pará de Minas\t 6.Itaúna\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            rota[i] = input.nextInt(); 
        }

        System.out.println("\nROTA: \n");

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            System.out.printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, cid[rota[i]-1]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
            km_rodados = km_rodados + km[rota[i]][rota[i+1]];
    }
        System.out.printf("\nKilômetros rodados: %d\n", km_rodados);
    } 
}
```

Até a parte de coletar a rota e exibir elas em ordem beleza, mas na hora de calcular os km, o for para em 5. Dá um help ai, não consegui pensar em outra maneira de calcular isso.

Comment: o array 'km' 6x6 com as ditâncias entre as cidades funciona como? Betim é a cidade "3" e Itaúna é a Cidade "6", portanto, a distância entre Betim e Itaúna está em 'km[2][5]' ("3-1=2" e "6-1=5")?

Comment: Seria mais ou menos, o usuario preencheu o array com (5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4), entao vai ser a distancia da cidade "5" e a cidade "3", cidade "3" até a cidade "1", e assim por diante, ou seja, no array km[4][2] (porque vai começar do 0)a distancia entre Pará de Minas e Betim é 48.

Comment: substituir o último for: "for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)" por "for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)" resolve o problema?

Comment: continua dando erro :/

Comment: Eu acho que seu código é um exercício, mas se não for, eu sugiro refatorá-lo, pois a lógica dele é muito obscura, além disso, ele é bem inflexível (por exemplo, se você quiser trabalhar com 7 cidades ao invés de 6, vai ter que mudar muita coisa nesse código).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código abaixo resolve o seu problema:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rotas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] km = {{0, 20, 32, 45, 85, 90}, {20, 0, 20, 40, 65, 70}, {32, 20, 0, 25, 48, 49}, 
                {45, 40, 25, 0, 39, 52}, {85, 65, 48, 39, 0, 36}, {90, 70, 49, 52, 36, 0}};

        int[] rota = new int[6];
        String[] cid = {"Belo Horizonte", "Contagem", "Betim", "Juatuba", "Pará de Minas", "Itaúna"};
        int km_rodados = 0;

        System.out.println("Distância entre Pará de Minas e Betim: "+km[4][2]);

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
                System.out.printf("%d\t", km[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Digite sua rota: \n\n1. Belo Horizonte\t2. Contagem\t3. Betim\n"
                + "4. Juatuba\t5. Pará de Minas\t 6.Itaúna\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            rota[i] = input.nextInt(); 
        }

        System.out.println("\nROTA: \n");

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            System.out.printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, cid[rota[i]-1]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i+1 < rota.length; i++){
            int idDaCidade = rota[i]-1;
            int idDaProximaCidade = rota[i+1]-1;
            int kmsEntreAsCidades = km[idDaCidade][idDaProximaCidade];
//          System.out.println("Distância entre "+cid[idDaCidade]+" e "+cid[idDaProximaCidade]+": "+kmsEntreAsCidades);
            km_rodados += kmsEntreAsCidades; //Equivalente a "km_rodados = km_rodados + kmsEntreAsCidades;"
//          System.out.println("Total de kms rodados até agora: "+km_rodados);
        }

        System.out.printf("\nKilômetros rodados: %d\n", km_rodados);
    } 
}
```

O problema estava dentro do último for, eu substitui este `for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)` por um `for(int i = 0; i+1 < rota.length; i++)`, que irá rodar até a distância entre a penúltima cidade e a última serem somadas. Além disso, dentro do for estou pegando do array `rota` os "ids" das Cidades (que na verdade é o índice delas no array `cid`) escolhidas pelo usuário; para então obter a distância entre estas cidades através de seus "ids", usando o array `km`que possui as distâncias entre as cidades, assim: `km[idDaCidade][idDaProximaCidade]`.

Comment: Nossa, valeu mesmo pela ajuda!